# Hi, i have a problem with segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small sorting program with vector of pairs. But I'm getting a segmentation fault. I want to make a program that gets as input an vector of pairs containing files with there names and sizes, sorts the vector by the sizes of the files...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

pair<string, int> min (vector<pair<string, int>> list){
    pair<string, int> min;
    for(int i = 0;i < list.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < list.size(); i++){
            if(list[i].second <= list[j].second)
                min = list[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

vector<pair<string, int>> sort (vector<pair<string, int>>& list){
    vector<pair<string, int>> sorted;
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++){
        sorted.push_back(min(list));
        list.erase(list.begin()+(i-1));
    }
    return sorted;
}

int main(){
    vector<pair<string, int>> files = {
        {"f1", 30},
        {"f2", 50},
        {"f3", 25},
        {"f4", 42},
        {"f5", 10}
    };
    //min(files);
    sort(files);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that after `list.erase(list.begin()+(i-1));` the size of the vector has changed and so you need to recalculate the size and the indices.

Comment: `for(int j = 1; j < list.size(); i++)` the increment is on the wrong variable. Further, you are using two nested "for"s to compute the minimum, which is very suspicious.

Comment: When `i=0;` what do you expect `list.begin()+(i-1)` to be?

Comment: I cannot understand the logic behind your `min`  function ...

Comment: Note that you could use `std::sort`, with a customized comparison function.

Comment: [^^^^ that](https://godbolt.org/z/6f3jfd6hM). In which most of this becomes obsolete.

Comment: My guess would be the homework is to implement insertion sort and people keep implementing extraction sort instead.

Answer (score 2):

##### Problem 1

The **problem** is that after `list.erase(list.begin()+(i-1));` the size of the vector has changed and so you need to recalculate the size and the indices used.

##### Problem 2

Additionally, for the inner loop involving `j` you're incrementing the outer loop variable `i`:

```
//------------------------------vvvv---->this should be j
for(int j = 1; j < list.size(); i++)
```

##### Problem 3

```
//-----------------------v------>what if i = 0? Undefined behavior
list.erase(list.begin()+(i-1));
```

In the above shown statement when `i = 0` the expression `list.erase(list.begin()+(0-1))` will lead to **undefined behavior** which is most probably the cause of seg fault you're observing.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

For example [here](https://onlinegdb.com/YTRpdJbb6) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7jKxEDrCr4nQE1tX) it crashes.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Note

There may be additional logical problems in your code.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: How is 1 a problem? At no point does he use an iterator that isn't freshly generated or a cached size.